# probability to choose the same number in a set

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose a set of numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and a set of entity $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ (with $n,m$ any real number).
How can I compute the probability that each entity choose the same number in the set?

Comment: Hint: What's the probability that each entity chooses the number 1?

Comment: you mean $m,n$ natural number?

Comment: I mean, if for example the set is of {1,2,3,4,5,6} numbers and we have 2 entity that n=6 and m=2.
How much is the probability that these two entities choose the same number in the set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $m=2$.  Entity 1 can choose any number, then entity 2 needs to choose the same one, which has probability $\frac 1n$.  Now, if $m=3$ you get another factor $\frac 1n$ because the third one has to choose the same number again.  Generally it is $\frac 1{n^{m-1}}$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Where can I see some theory notions about this?

Comment: @user1938352:  The search term is combinatorics.  There is a classic two volume text that I can't locate right now, but I have the first and it is great.